# RESTful api best practice for POST api request and response objects modelling

Tags: rest, spring-rest

For my POST API, in my spring boot application, my request and response objects are almost the same, except for the fact that my response object has an additional "timestamp" field.

Should i keep them *separate* ? OR have a *single common POJO* with all the fields ?

Does the RESTful style have some guidelines for this, or we are free to choose our approach ?

Links to any documentation, if relevant, will be tremendously helpful !

Thanks !!

Edit 1 : 
Here is my **Request object** :-

```
public class UserRequest {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
}
```

and my **Response object**:-

```
public class UserResponse {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private LocalDate date;
}
```

I am using this for a Spring boot JPA application.

Should i merge the into a single class called **"User"** and keep all the fields including the "date" ? 
Or should keep the request and response objects separate ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> Does the RESTful style have some guidelines for this, or we are free to choose our approach ?

REST doesn't have a lot to say about message design, other than noting that we should be concentrating on using standardized media types and communicating which types we are using in easily standardized ways.

If you look at the definition of an HTTP message, you'll see that requests and responses share the same [basic definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) - the sole distinction between the two is the composition of the [start-line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1), which is either a [request-line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) or a [status-line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2).

But you might notice that even though the schema are basically the same (meaning that you *could* choose to use the same underlying data structure in both cases), in most typed languages the request and response will be treated as different types (because the *semantics* are different).

Comment: I'm looking from more of an RESTful - JPA application development perspective at this. Edited my question for more details